# Image hyperlink in PHP

Tags: php, drupal

I have the following PHP code for one of my blocks

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>
<div class = "order-help">
<div class = "rc-img"><img src = "<?php print $base_url; ?>/sites/all/themes/businessconnect/images/contacts-box.jpg" alt = ""/></div>
</div>
```

This displays the image fine in my block but i also want to make the image a hyperlink to some other page. For that i used the following code

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>
<div class = "order-help">
<?php print( <a href="http://mylink.com/path/">
<div class = "rc-img">
<img src = "<?php print $base_url; ?>/sites/all/themes/businessconnect/images/contacts-box.jpg" alt = ""/></div>
</a>' ); ?>
</div>
```

But it does not work. What am i missing?
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `<a>` tag to the HTML.

```
<div class = "rc-img">
    <a href="http://mylink.com/path/">
        <img src="<?php print $base_url; ?>/sites/all/themes/businessconnect/images/contacts-box.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Your code wasn't working because `print` needs you to pass it a string, and you also had `<?php print $base_url ?>` inside of a `<?php` block.

Comment: Better use url() to get the url. Relative by default, add extra params to get absolute URL. 
<a href="<?php print url('path'); ?>">. 
This should work for the image src as well. For extra fun, use drupal_get_path() to get the theme's path.
Both functions are documented in api.drupal.org.